# Which grid is good for Asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

I need some suggestions in choosing the grid for the asp.net MVC 5 based application. I need the grid to have modal popup for adding and editing records

Answer (score 0):

"The grid" being a plugin choice to use in your MVC application? Try out Kendo UI! Modal popup would be a potential customization you could make for adding/editing records in a data grid.

Or write it yourself in good old javascript ;)